# Python: Save a variable as HTML file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2

This is probably a very simple question but I did not find any solution until now and I have been around this hours

I have one HTML file "teste.html"
I Use jinja 2 to change my HTML

```
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template("teste.html")

template_vars = {"Client" : Name}
    
html_out = template.render(template_vars)

type(html_out)
```

finish with a html_out that is s string

```
type(html_out)
Out[60]: str
```

Now I want to save this html_out in a HTML document

How can I do that?

Comment: What's the problem? Writing a string to a file is the same no matter where it came from.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can just write the HTML string you have to a file with `.html` extension.

For example:

```
htmlstring = ... # Your HTML data
with open("yourhtmlfile.html", "w") as file:
    file.write(htmlstring)
```

Comment: Many thanks, Challe!! You first "open" as a document and after save them?

Comment: The with statement takes care of closing the file

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want to save your `str` to a file. Saving a file in python can be done like:

```
with open('teste_rendered.html', 'w') as file:
    file.write(html_out)
```

Note: The location where the file actually saves depends on how you run your python script.