# Clean code to incorporate raw csv data into html template using Python, Pandas, and/or Jinja2

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv, jinja2

HTML Template with field for RAW CSV DATA:

```
<body>
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
{{ RAW CSV DATA }}
</pre>
</body>
```

This short tutorial shows how to read the template and render a new html but not how to save the output as another file, for example, "result.html".

https://techmonger.github.io/69/jinja2-render-html/

Currently using Pandas to process and write RAW CSV DATA to a file named "test.csv":

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Ticker data
input_file = 'tick.csv'

# Read csv input file Date, Adj_high, Adj_low into Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, usecols=[0,9,10], 
            parse_dates=['DATE'], date_parser = pd.to_datetime)

# Write DATE, ADJ_HIGH, ADJ_LOW to csv file
df.to_csv('test.csv', index=False)
```

Example of file "test.csv" containing RAW CSV DATA:

```
DATE,ADJ_HIGH,ADJ_LOW
2018-04-27,164.33,160.63
2018-04-30,167.26,161.84
2018-05-01,169.20,165.27
2018-05-02,177.75,173.80
2018-05-03,177.50,174.44
```

If possible how might one use Pandas to write RAW CSV DATA to the html template? Alternatively how would one use Python/Pandas, with or without Jinja2, to read the test.csv file and write it into the HTML template between the "pre" tags?

The resulting HTML file looks like this:

```
<body>
<pre id="csv" style="display: none">
DATE,ADJ_HIGH,ADJ_LOW
2018-04-27,164.33,160.63
2018-04-30,167.26,161.84
2018-05-01,169.20,165.27
2018-05-02,177.75,173.80
2018-05-03,177.50,174.44
</pre>
</body>
```

Comment: [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), if a file is not specified, returns as a string. `csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)` then this string can be incorporated normally.

Answer (score 2):

As commented by Henry Ecker, too, `to_csv` without a positional argument returns just the string, so..

```py
import jinja2

t = jinja2.Template('<pre>{{ raw_csv_data }}</pre>')
csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
html_string = t.render(raw_csv_data=csv_data)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer which partly solves my problem. However it may not be clear in my question I want to read the template.html, read the csv data in pandas, and save the combined file as result.html. This short tutorial shows how to read the template.html and render a template:  https://techmonger.github.io/69/jinja2-render-html/. My Jinja2 and Python skills are not used often so then how does one save the merged html as another output file for example "result.html"?

Comment: Found the answer to how to write html string to file as the selected answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619895/python-save-a-variable-as-html-file.

Comment: @SystemTheory sorry, I saw your comment just now, but I'm glad you figured it out! :)

Answer (score 0):

This code works to write the output file without newlines in the csv data:

```
import jinja2
import pandas as pd

# AAPL EOD data file
input_file = 'AAPL.csv'

# Output File
output_file = 'jinja_test.html'

# Read csv input file Date, Adj_high, Adj_low into Pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, usecols=[0,9,10], 
            parse_dates=[0], date_parser = pd.to_datetime)

t = jinja2.Template('<pre>{{ raw_csv_data }}</pre>')
csv_data = df.to_csv(index=False)
html_string = t.render(raw_csv_data=csv_data)

# Write result of render as html output file 
with open(output_file, "w", newline='') as file:
    file.write(html_string)
```